# Dynamically updating jquery mobile collapsible

Tags: jquery, mobile, dynamic

I have a collapsible inside of a panel that I am dynamically loading with contacts from the phone. For some reason when i dynamically add the content it is displayed as plain text. I've tried the refresh method and for some reason it still won't work. Thanks a ton.

here is the div the collapsible is contained in:

```
        <div id="srchResults" data-role="collapsible-set" data-inset="false" data-theme="c" data-content-theme="d" data-mini="true">
            <div id="resultdiv" data-role="collapsible">
        </div>
```

here is the jquery:

```
for (var i=0; i<contacts.length; i++) {

            $('#resultdiv').append("<h3>"+contacts[i].name.formatted+"</h3>"+"<p>"+'test'+"</p>");
            $("#srchResults").collapsibleset("refresh");
            $( "#mypanel" ).trigger( "updatelayout" ); //updates the panel that contains the collapsible

        }
```

Comment: each contact will be displayed in the set with its own collapsible content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please try this:

```
for (var i=0; i<contacts.length; i++) {

        $('#srchResults').append("<div id='resultdiv"+i+"' data-role='collapsible'><h3>"+contacts[i].name.formatted+"</h3>"+"<p>"+'test'+"</p></div>");


    } $("#srchResults").collapsibleset("refresh");$( "#mypanel" ).trigger( "updatelayout" ); //updates the panel that contains the collapsible
```